# Declare instance variable in anonymous class inside enum

Tags: groovy, enums, anonymous-class

For example, this code in Groovy works well:

```
def f = new Runnable() {
    def test = "Hello!"
    @Override
    void run() {
        println(test)
    }
}

f.run()
```

It prints `Hello!` to console. The main idea here is that it uses instance variable inside anonymous class.
But when you move such anonymous class instantiation to enum constant's argument, now it does not work:

```
enum E {
    E1(new Runnable() {
        def test = "Hello!"
        @Override
        void run() {
            println(test)
        }
    })

    def runnable

    E(def r) {
        runnable = r
    }
}

E.E1.runnable.run()
```

Error is shown in console:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
ideaGroovyConsole.groovy: 23: Apparent variable 'test' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'test' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 23, column 21.
               println(test)
                       ^
```

It says that variable was found in static scope (why?) but it even cannot use it as static field.

However, it works without variable inside anonymous class:

```
enum E {
    E1(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        void run() {
            println("Hello!")
        }
    })

    def runnable

    E(def r) {
        runnable = r
    }
}

E.E1.runnable.run()
```

How to force Groovy to work with instance variables inside anonymous classes like in Java?

Comment: Inner classes is one of those areas where Groovy strays a bit from Java: http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_inner_classes

Comment: @bdkosher yes, I have read this [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html) but problem in my question suprised me more then mentioned differences on the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doable with Groovy as well, although you have to refer to `test` field using `this.test` field access notation to satisfy groovyc compiler:

```
enum E {
    E1(new Runnable() {
        def test = "Hello!"

        @Override
        void run() {
            println(this.test)
        }
    })

    def runnable

    E(def r) {
        runnable = r
    }
}

E.E1.runnable.run()
```